# Enable and disable buttons in the AppBar using Binding

Tags: xaml, data-binding

I have an applicationbar with 2 buttons "edit" and "save" on a xaml page.

When the pages is loaded the "edit" button has to be enabled and the "save" button disabled.

When you press the "edit" button the "save" button gets enabled same for when you press the "save" button.

The problem is that both buttons are disabled when the page is loaded.

My code:

Button properties:

```
 private bool _editButtonIsEnabled;
    public bool EditButtonIsEnabled
    {
        get
        {
            return _saveButtonIsEnabled;
        }
        set
        {
            _editButtonIsEnabled = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("EditButtonIsEnabled");
        }
    }

    private bool _saveButtonIsEnabled;
    public bool SaveButtonIsEnabled
    {
        get
        {
            return _saveButtonIsEnabled;
        }
        set
        {
            _saveButtonIsEnabled = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SaveButtonIsEnabled");
        }
    }
```

Xaml page with binding:

```
 <Sh:AdvancedApplicationBar>
        <Grid>
            <Sh:AdvancedApplicationBarIconButton Text="edit"
                                                 IconUri="/Assets/ActionBarButtons/btn_actionbar_edit.png"
                                                 Command="{Binding EditFavorithProgramsCommand}"
                                                 VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                                                 IsEnabled="{Binding EditButtonIsEnabled}"/>
            <Sh:AdvancedApplicationBarIconButton Text="save"
                                                 IconUri="/Assets/ActionBarButtons/btn_actionbar_save.png"
                                                 Command="{Binding SaveFavorithProgramsCommand}"
                                                 VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                                                 IsEnabled="{Binding SaveButtonIsEnabled}" />
        </Grid>
    </Sh:AdvancedApplicationBar>
```

Answer (score 0):

you got a typo in your EditButtonIsEnabled getter

```
public bool EditButtonIsEnabled
{
    get
    {
        return _saveButtonIsEnabled;
    }
    //...
}
```

Comment: Indeed but the buttons stay unabled when the page is loaded.